# How can I construct a Stored Procedure that will return a result set containing many calculated values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, subquery, calculated-field

These are the values that I need to return from a stored procedure:

```
Description
Week 1 Usage
Week 2 Usage
Usage Variance
Week 1 Price
Week 2 Price
Price Variance
% of Price Variance
```

The three fields with "Variance" in their name are calculated fields based on the other values, and the "Week" partitions have to be calculated based on date parameters. So the actual (most pertinent) fields that reside in the database tables are:

```
Description
Usage
Price
InvoiceDate
```

The parameters provided by the user are:

```
Unit
DateBegin
DateEnd
```

The variables I think I will need to declare in the stored procedure are:

```
DECLARE 
@Week1Begin datetime, 
@Week1End datetime, 
@Week2Begin datetime, 
@Week2End datetime, 
@Week1Usage varchar(30),
@Week2Usage varchar(30),
@Week1Price varchar(30),
@Week2Price varchar(30),
@UsageVariance varchar(30),
@PriceVariance varchar(30),
@PercentageOfPriceVariance varchar(30)
```

`Week1Begin` and `Week1End` will have to be computed based on the value provided by the user in the `DateBegin` parameter (e.g., if `DateBegin` is 12/27/15, `Week1Begin` would be 12/27/2015 and `Week1End` would be 1/2/2016);

`Week2Begin` and `Week2End` would be similar, but their span could be fewer than seven days and if longer than that 7 days at most (`Week2End` would be "reduced" to a prior date as needed).

So although there's a lot of calculating going on, the raw data is pretty sparse. It's basically the four fields mentioned above (Description, Usage, Price, and InvoiceDate), which are available from the `InvoiceDetail` table.

My biggest dilemma is that much of this data is returned from an existing stored procedure that might be best to copy and extend, but I am no SQL expert by any means - I can write simple `SELECT` and `UPDATE`, etc., statements, but dancing with temp tables and such relational gyrations are pretty much beyond me.

So creating a new stored procedure based on an existing one seems fraught with danger; OTOH, I wonder if it would be possible to retrieve the data I need using a rather minimal stored procedure with a complex query statement containing multiple sub-selects.

Again, complex SQL is not my forte by any means, so I may be "way off" here, but here is my pseudo-SQL:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[myFunkySP]
    @Unit varchar(25),
    @BegDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
As

// Create a mostly-empty-for-now temp table
Select  Description,
    Week1Begin,
    Week1End,
    Week2Begin,
    Week2End,
    Week1Usage,
    Week2Usage,
    Week1Price,
    Week2Price,
    UsageVariance,
    PriceVariance
    PercentageOfPriceVariance
    Into    #TempItems
    From    InvoiceDetail Ind
    Where   Ind.Unit = @Unit
    and Ind.InvoiceDate Between @BegDate and @EndDate


begin

    Update #TempItems set 
    Week1Begin = // val from@BegDate
    Week1End = // do some date math to determine; maybe a Function called GetEndOfWeek(Week1Begin)? 
    Week2Begin = // do some date math to determine (1 day beyond Week1End val)
    Week2End = // val from@EndDate
    Week1Usage = SELECT SUM(USAGE) FROM InvoiceDetail WHERE UNIT = @UNIT, DATE BETWEEN Week1Begin AND Week1End 
    Week2Usage = SELECT SUM(USAGE) FROM InvoiceDetail WHERE UNIT = @UNIT, DATE BETWEEN Week2Begin AND Week2End 
    Week1Price = SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM InvoiceDetail WHERE UNIT = @UNIT, DATE BETWEEN Week1Begin AND Week1End
    Week2Price = SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM InvoiceDetail WHERE UNIT = @UNIT, DATE BETWEEN Week2Begin AND Week2End
    UsageVariance = (Week2Usage - Week1Usage)
    PriceVariance = (Week2Price - Week1Price)
    PercentageOfPriceVariance = (PriceVariance div week2Price)

    // now select * from the temp table to return everything?
```

Otherwise (if the above won't work or is not feasible), I was thinking I might have to do some 9-X-Uglier-than-a-bag-of-butts query polluted with beaucoup subqueries, something like:

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION, 
    (SELECT SUM(USAGE) FROM InvoiceDetail
        WHERE UNIT = @UNIT, InvoiceDate BETWEEN :firstWeekBegin AND :firstWeekEnd as Week1Usage), 
    (SELECT SUM(USAGE) FROM InvoiceDetail
        WHERE UNIT = @UNIT, InvoiceDate BETWEEN :secondWeekBegin AND :secondWeekEnd as Week2Usage), 
    SELECT PRICE FROM InvoiceDetail 
        WHERE UNIT = @UNIT, InvoiceDate = firstWeekBegin as Week1Price), 
    (SELECT PRICE FROM InvoiceDetail    
        WHERE UNIT = @UNIT, InvoiceDate = secondWeekBegin as Week2Price), 
FROM InvoiceDetail
WHERE UNIT = @UNIT, InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BEGDATE AND @ENDATE ORDER BY PRODUCTS
```

Say it aint' so, Joe!

Even if that convoluted query is sort of workable, it still doesn't give me the calculated values I need (UsageVariance, PriceVariance, and PercentageOfPriceVariance).

So what do I need to do to create a stored procedure that will return the results I need?

Comment: As a side note: why are so many native English speakers writing "Stored Procedure" frequently? As far as I learned English, you only capitalize words at the beginning of a sentence, or when they represent something Holy, Royal, or a Geographical place - neither of which applies here - this is just simply a **procedure** that is **stored** inside your database (SQL Server in this case) - why this urge to capitalize those initials? `</rant>`

Comment: I prefer the German method of capitalizing all nouns; every language probably has its good points. I like the inverted question and exclamation marks that Spanish uses at the start of the sentence, and its as-short-as-possible "y" (or sometimes "e")  for "and," "o" (or sometimes "u") for "or," and "a" for "to."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found by following lad2025's advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829753/how-can-i-compute-values-in-a-tsql-update-statement).

Basically, define them in the table creation like so:

```
USAGEVARIANCE   AS WEEK2USAGE - WEEK1USAGE,
PRICEVARIANCE   AS WEEK2PRICE - WEEK1PRICE,
PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE  AS (WEEK2PRICE - WEEK1PRICE) / WEEK1PRICE
```

...for more context:

```
WEEK1USAGE DECIMAL(18,10),
WEEK1PRICE DECIMAL(18,10),
WEEK2USAGE DECIMAL(18,10),
WEEK2PRICE DECIMAL(18,10),
USAGEVARIANCE   AS WEEK2USAGE - WEEK1USAGE,
PRICEVARIANCE   AS WEEK2PRICE - WEEK1PRICE,
PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE  AS (WEEK2PRICE - WEEK1PRICE) / WEEK1PRICE
```

Thereafter, you don't have to consider them in INSERT statements - the calculated values are added automagically when the values they rely on are added.

Answer (score 1):

Extended comment, not an answer
The UPDATE part is not needed. At first you need to calculate week1end and week2bigin at the bigining of the SP. After this, the SELECT statement is prety straight forward –

```
    DECLARE @Week1End datetime ,@Week2begin datetime

    Select  Description,
    @BegDate  BegDate,
    @Week1End Week1End,
    @Week1End Week2Begin,
    @EndDate EndDate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END) Week1Usage,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END) Week2Usage,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) Week1Price,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) -
   SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END) UsageVariance,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END)  -
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) PriceVariance,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END)  -
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) )
    /     SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END)     
    PercentageOfPriceVariance
    From    InvoiceDetail Ind
    Where   Ind.Unit = @Unit
    AND @Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: It seems pretty much like an answer to me, but comparing this to the other answer by Ramazan Binarbasi, does this return a table, or do I do need to add something else for that to happen with the code above?

Comment: I'm trying to create an SP almost exactly like that, to see what results I get, but it won't compile; I asked a new quest about that problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772214/where-is-the-incorrect-syntax-near-sum-in-this-sp

Comment: It seems I missed a comma, SQLFiddle was down at the time, no SQL arround, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function that returns table.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx