# Where is the 'Incorrect syntax near 'SUM'' in this SP?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sum

I get, "*Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure duckbilledPlatypi, Line 21 Incorrect syntax near 'SUM'.*" with this MS SQL Server Stored Procedure when I try to execute it in Visual Studio (after creating it from within Server Explorer):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[duckbilledPlatypi]
    @Unit varchar(25),
    @BegDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
AS

DECLARE 
@Week1End datetime,
@Week2begin datetime

    Select  Description,
    @BegDate  BegDate,
    @Week1End Week1End,
    @Week1End Week2Begin,
    @EndDate EndDate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END) Week1Usage,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END) Week2Usage,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) Week1Price,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) -
   SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END) UsageVariance
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END)  -
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) PriceVariance,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END)  -
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) )
    / SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) PercentageOfPriceVariance
    From    InvoiceDetail Ind
    Where   Ind.Unit = @Unit
    AND @Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @EndDate
```

The problem line is:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END)  -
```

In context, the entire statement portion is:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END)  -
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) PriceVariance,
```

?

I thought maybe I needed to encase the statement in another pair of parens, like so:

```
*(SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END)  - 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END)) PriceVariance,*
```

...but I still get the same exact err msg with that.

### UPDATE

With this (HoneyBadger's answer):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[variancePriceByProductWithPriceChangePercentage]
    @Unit varchar(25),
    @BegDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
AS

DECLARE 
@Week1End datetime,
@Week2begin datetime

    Select  Description,
    @BegDate  BegDate,
    @Week1End Week1End,
    @Week1End Week2Begin,
    @EndDate EndDate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END) 
Week1Usage,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END) 
Week2Usage,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) 
Week1Price,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) -
   SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END) 
UsageVariance,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END)  -
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) 
PriceVariance,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END)  -
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) )
    / SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) 
PercentageOfPriceVariance
    From    InvoiceDetail Ind
    Where   Ind.Unit = @Unit
    AND Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @EndDate
    Group By Description,
    @BegDate,
    @Week1End,
    @Week1End,
    @EndDate
```

I get the following fingerwags:

*Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Procedure variancePriceByProductWithPriceChangePercentage, Line 30
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure variancePriceByProductWithPriceChangePercentage, Line 16
Invalid column name 'Usage'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure variancePriceByProductWithPriceChangePercentage, Line 17
Invalid column name 'Usage'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure variancePriceByProductWithPriceChangePercentage, Line 20
Invalid column name 'Usage'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure variancePriceByProductWithPriceChangePercentage, Line 21
Invalid column name 'Usage'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure variancePriceByProductWithPriceChangePercentage, Line 23
Invalid column name 'Usage'.*

Comment: Add a `group by` clause

Comment: Where, and with what values (grouping by what)?

Comment: And you are missing a comma after `UsageVariance` (It's not the line reported that's the problem, it's the line above it)

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Missing commas are why I like to start a new line with a comma instead of having one on the end of the previous line. It's easy to spot when they are all in a single column.

Comment: @Ghost: Thanks, that's a good tip; a comma at the beginning of a line always looked 9-X-uglier-than-a-bag-of-butts to me, but now I grok the logic in that methodology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, you should add a `group by`. Others have pointed out you had a missing comma, I added that as well:

```
    Select  Description,
    @BegDate  BegDate,
    @Week1End Week1End,
    @Week1End Week2Begin,
    @EndDate EndDate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END) Week1Usage,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END) Week2Usage,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) Week1Price,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) -
   SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END) UsageVariance,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END)  -
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) PriceVariance,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Usage ELSE 0 END)  -
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) )
    / SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) PercentageOfPriceVariance
    From    InvoiceDetail Ind
    Where   Ind.Unit = @Unit
    AND Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @EndDate
    Group By Description
```

**edit:** Apparently the variables in the `group by` are wrong

Comment: But the "@" in "@Ind.InvoiceDate" should be removed, right? So that it's simply "Ind.InvoiceDate"?

Comment: Thanks; I've added an Update to my question.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, updated answer, the variables shouldn't be in the `group by`.

Answer (score 2):

Typo:

```
SUM(CASE [..snip...][ END) UsageVariance
                                        ^--missing comma
```

which is why you get the syntax error on the `SUM` in the next line.  you have essentially `SUM(...) SUM(...)` which is invalid.