# How can I compute values in a TSQL Update statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, calculated-columns

I want to create three temp tables and then combine their contents like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP1
MEMBERITEMCODE VARCHAR(25),
WEEK1USAGE VARCHAR(25),
WEEK1PRICE VARCHAR(25);

INSERT INTO #TEMP1 (MEMBERITEMCODE, WEEK1USAGE, WEEK1PRICE)
SELECT MEMBERITEMCODE, SUM(QTYSHIPPED), PRICE 
FROM INVOICEDETAIL 
WHERE UNIT=@UNIT AND INVOICEDATE BETWEEN @BEGDATE AND @WEEK1END
GROUP BY MEMBERITEMCODE, PRICE

CREATE TABLE #TEMP2
MEMBERITEMCODE VARCHAR(25),
WEEK2USAGE VARCHAR(25),
WEEK2PRICE VARCHAR(25);

INSERT INTO #TEMP2 (MEMBERITEMCODE, WEEK2USAGE, WEEK2PRICE)
SELECT MEMBERITEMCODE, SUM(QTYSHIPPED), PRICE 
FROM INVOICEDETAIL 
WHERE UNIT=@UNIT AND INVOICEDATE BETWEEN @WEEK2BEGIN AND @ENDDATE
GROUP BY MEMBERITEMCODE, PRICE

CREATE TABLE #TEMP3
MEMBERITEMCODE VARCHAR(25),
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(200),
THIS VARCHAR(25),
THAT VARCHAR(25),
THEOTHERTHING VARCHAR(25);

INSERT INTO #TEMP3 (MEMBERITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, THIS, THAT, THEOTHERTHING)
SELECT MEMBERITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, THIS, THAT, THEOTHERTHING 
FROM INVOICEDETAIL 
WHERE UNIT=@UNIT AND INVOICEDATE BETWEEN @BEGDATE AND @ENDDATE

CREATE TABLE #TEMPCOMBINED
MEMBERITEMCODE VARCHAR(25),
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(200),
THIS VARCHAR(25),
THAT VARCHAR(25),
THEOTHERTHING VARCHAR(25),
WEEK1USAGE VARCHAR(25),
WEEK1PRICE VARCHAR(25);
WEEK2USAGE VARCHAR(25),
WEEK2PRICE VARCHAR(25),
USAGEVARIANCE VARCHAR(25),
PRICEVARIANCE VARCHAR(25),
PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE VARCHAR(25);

INSERT INTO #TEMPCOMBINED (MEMBERITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, THIS, THAT, THEOTHERTHING, WEEK1USAGE, WEEK1PRICE, WEEK2USAGE, WEEK2PRICE, USAGEVARIANCE,
PRICEVARIANCE, PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE)
SELECT T1.MEMBERITEMCODE, T3.DESCRIPTION, T3.THIS, T3.THAT, T3.THEOTHERTHING, T1.WEEK1USAGE, T1.WEEK1PRICE, T2.WEEK2USAGE, T2.WEEK2PRICE, NULL,  NULL,  NULL
FROM #TEMP1 T1
LEFT JOIN #TEMP2 T2 ON T1.MEMBERITEMCODE = T2.MEMBERITEMCODE
LEFT JOIN #TEMP3 T3 ON T1.MEMBERITEMCODE = T3.MEMBERITEMCODE
```

Now I want to replace the placeholder Nulls in the calculated fields, but don't know how to do that. My best idea so far is:

```
UPDATE #TEMPCOMBINED
SET USAGEVARIANCE = WEEK2USAGE - WEEK1USAGE,
PRICEVARIANCE = WEEK2PRICE - WEEK1PRICE,
PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE = (WEEK2PRICE - WEEK1PRICE) / WEEK1PRICE
```

Is there a better way (one that actually works, for instance)?

Comment: You can't do calculations on `varchar` values. EIther change the type in the temp table, or cast the values in the calculation.

Comment: [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424526) Something like this? When you insert data(without 3 last columns) they will be calculated

Comment: Have you tried running that statement against the tables you created? AFAICT your statement looks OK. Also having all data in VARCHAR's is a terrible idea.

Comment: Following Guffa's advice the first column might look something like this: `USAGEVARIANCE = cast(cast(WEEK2USAGE as numeric(11, 4)) - cast(WEEK1USAGE as numeric(11, 4)) as varchar(25)), ...`

Comment: @lad2025: You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using computed columns:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPCOMBINED(
  MEMBERITEMCODE VARCHAR(25),
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(200),
  THIS VARCHAR(25),
  THAT VARCHAR(25),
  THEOTHERTHING VARCHAR(25),
  WEEK1USAGE DECIMAL(18,10),
  WEEK1PRICE DECIMAL(18,10),
  WEEK2USAGE DECIMAL(18,10),
  WEEK2PRICE DECIMAL(18,10),
  USAGEVARIANCE   AS WEEK2USAGE - WEEK1USAGE,
  PRICEVARIANCE   AS WEEK2PRICE - WEEK1PRICE,
  PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE  AS (WEEK2PRICE - WEEK1PRICE) / WEEK1PRICE
);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424526)**</kbd>

And skip them in `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO #TEMPCOMBINED (MEMBERITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, THIS, THAT, THEOTHERTHING, WEEK1USAGE, WEEK1PRICE, WEEK2USAGE, WEEK2PRICE)
SELECT T1.MEMBERITEMCODE, T3.DESCRIPTION, T3.THIS, T3.THAT, T3.THEOTHERTHING, T1.WEEK1USAGE, T1.WEEK1PRICE, T2.WEEK2USAGE, T2.WEEK2PRICE
FROM #TEMP1 T1
LEFT JOIN #TEMP2 T2 ON T1.MEMBERITEMCODE = T2.MEMBERITEMCODE
LEFT JOIN #TEMP3 T3 ON T1.MEMBERITEMCODE = T3.MEMBERITEMCODE
```

*Warning:*

Division by `WEEK1PRICE` so you could add
`(WEEK2PRICE - WEEK1PRICE) / NULLIF(WEEK1PRICE,0)` to avoid Math exception or add `CHECK` constraint to ensure that `WEEK1PRICE` is not 0.

Answer (score 3):

First thing: why are you using varchar datatype for following columns?

`USAGEVARIANCE, ,WEEK2USAGE,WEEK1USAGE,PRICEVARIANCE , WEEK2PRICE , WEEK1PRICE, PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE, WEEK2PRICE , WEEK1PRICE,WEEK1PRICE ;`

It is better to use decimal or integer data types. As you are using `sum()` function to calculate its value and it will return int/decimal value

Second: you can calculate `USAGEVARIANCE,PRICEVARIANCE,PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE` while inserting into the table. For example:

```
select a,b, (a-b) as USAGEVARIANCE, (c-d) as PRICEVARIANCE from table
```

etc and then insert it into the temporary table

Comment: I agree about the data types, but that's how the original tables have them defined. I will change it/make it right as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Update column in one table you can use 
Cross join on simple join

For example:

```
Update m
Set col1 = col1 - col2
From mytable m 
join mytable n On m.col2 = n.col2
```